# TFS 2017 Update 2: Delivery Plans error VS403173

Tags: tfs

When creating our first Delivery Plan in TFS 2017 Update 2 we get an error:

```
VS403173: Maximum number of team fields was exceeded.
```

The Delivery Plan has four teams. Three of the teams are newly and one was renamed (old). The renamed team seems to work fine as long as it is not the bottom team in the Delivery Plan. If it is on the bottom it shows the mentioned error for the bottom two teams. If it is in position 1, 2, or 3 only the bottom team has the error. The only difference between the new teams and the renamed team is the iteration start date. Also, if the three new teams are the only teams in the Delivery Plan the bottom one throws the error.

[image: Renamed Team on bottom]

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue when use an old team upgrade from update1. Did you got the same error if you are using four newly  created teams? And what's the result if you use totally three teams (two new, one old and the old is on the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by removing Area paths from the teams and setting the default Area path with sub-areas included.  This is instead of picking and choosing a bunch of paths. In our case we are fine with all Area paths.

Answer (score -1):

Delivery Plans is an extension from the marketplace, accessible from here http://tctfs:8080/tfs/_gallery/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans&targetId=ccd87be2-418f-4b5f-9474-502fd5da51bf

If you scroll to the bottom, there's a UserVoice link. You should raise an issue there, or browse for an existing record of your issue and up-vote it.